# Partition data consistently among worker processes

Tags: algorithm, performance, hash, consistency, consistent-hashing

I am looking for ideas on how I can equally distribute work on among predefined worker processes

I have an array of 'n' documents stored in Mongo and 'm' worker processes

Currently I have written an algorithm which is processed by each worker on startup

Algorithm: 
 1. Worker starts with its predefined worker Number 
 2. Get document list from Mongo 
 3. ForEach Document in Document List 
    { 
        Magic Number = Mod( Hash( Document Name ), m ) 
        If( Magic Number == My Worker Number ) 
        Add Document to My bucket list for specific action 
}

This algorithm does a fairly decent job but its not very efficient as the difference in the number of documents picked by each worker if off by a large factor ~30% from the average

So I am looking for some ideas on how I can make the workers distribute 'n' available documents equally or within some tolerance (~5%) from mean

Current infrastructure does not allow me to have a Master which can query Mongo and distribute the work to the workers

I did some online reading on consistent hashing (used by amazon Dynamo and Memcached) and it looks promising but haven't tried implementing and analyzing it but wanted to check if there are any other solutions or ideas out there which can be promising or is consistent hashing is the way to go?

Comment: Is it Ok for each worker to load all names (or name hashes) into memory? If yes, then it may sort list of names (or name hashes) and process all documents with array indices [n/m*i .. n/m*(i+1)-1], where `i` is the worker number.

Comment: By the way, what hash function are you using, what's its length (number of bits) and what are actual values for `m` and `n`? 30% deviation from average seems too large. Do you have a lot of documents with identical names maybe?